# Returning value after matching with Constant

Tags: apex, list

Requirement of the method - Get a MDMfield in parameter. Fetch records from an object with some conditions. Return the field which matches with the Constant value.

```
Public String Value(String parameter){
     String returnField;
     If ( parameter == Constant Value1){
      List<CustomObject> List = [SELECT Name 2 from CustomObject WHERE Field1=ABCD];
  returnField = get.List(1);
     }
     else if (parameter == Certain Constant Value2){
     List<CustomObject> List = [SELECT Name 1 from CustomObject WHERE Field1=ABCD];
  returnField = get.List(1);
     }
   //a few other similar conditions
return returnfield;
}
```

Question - Is this approach/syntax correct ? Is there any error in parameter passing/initialisation ?

Answer (score 1):

I would've used slightly different approach, if I know 'ABCD' would return me only one value then

```
CustomObject obj = [SELECT Name 2 from CustomObject WHERE Field1='ABCD' LIMIT 1];
returnField = obj.Name2;
```

and similar for the constant2. But I would be worried if the returned values from both constant1 & constant2 are more than one record.

A word of caution, you might need to overview your business requirement for that, it might be correct but not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Mahmood . Is there a way to optimise the number of IF-Else statements?

Comment: yeah, you could use a dynamics [soql](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to reduce the queries in your code, and only the field you are querying and the filter will be updated based on the parameter. But for your scenario, that would be an overkill. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`sObject.get()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) and a `Map`, you can probably make this easier to maintain:

```
private final Map<String, String> parametersToFields = new Map<String, String>
    {Constant1 => Field1, Constant2 => Field2};
Public String Value(string parameter)
{
    return System.query('SELECT ' + parametersToFields.get(parameter) + 
        ' from CustomObject WHERE Field1=\'ABCD\'').get(parametersToFields.get(parameter));
}
```